# Can two different users have the same Facebook third-party id in different applications?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Are Facebook third-party ids unique or two diff users can have the same third-party id in diff applications?

Comment: I mean ids that facebook application developers must share with third-party services instead of facebook user ids since January 1.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/431

Answer (score 1):

What I can tell you is that the same Facebook user will have a different third party id for two different applications. As the system was designed to prevent the third party services to access the Facebook uid it's most likely that third party id collision is prevented only within the same application.

By the way the deadline was extended to the 31 of January (http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/442).

Sorry that I can't give you more precision but if you have multiple applications I highly recommend that you store the application Id with the third party Id.